# Getting the coordinates of a sudoku block

Tags: c++, algorithm, multidimensional-array, range, sudoku

So I am try to solve a problem where I need to get the starting points of a sudoku block given a cell from the sudoku grid.

So for example given this board:

```
 2D-ARRAY COORDINATE

[0,0] [0,1] [0,2]  |  [0,3] [0,4] [0,5]  |  [0,6] [0,7] [0,8]
[1,0] [1,1] [1,2]  |  [1,3] [1,4] [1,5]  |  [1,6] [1,7] [1,8]
[2,0] [2,1] [2,2]  |  [2,3] [2,4] [2,5]  |  [2,6] [2,7] [2,8]
-------------------+---------------------+-------------------
[3,0] [3,1] [3,2]  |  [3,3] [3,4] [3,5]  |  [3,6] [3,7] [3,8]
[4,0] [4,1] [4,2]  |  [4,3] [4,4] [4,5]  |  [4,6] [4,7] [4,8]
[5,0] [5,1] [5,2]  |  [5,3] [5,4] [5,5]  |  [5,6] [5,7] [5,8]
-------------------+---------------------+-------------------
[6,0] [6,1] [6,2]  |  [6,3] [6,4] [6,5]  |  [6,6] [6,7] [6,8]
[7,0] [7,1] [7,2]  |  [7,3] [7,4] [7,5]  |  [7,6] [7,7] [7,8]
[8,0] [8,1] [8,2]  |  [8,3] [8,4] [8,5]  |  [8,6] [8,7] [8,8]
```

Assume [y,x]

If the given cell is [1,1], the the function should return 0-2 for the x value and 0-2 for the y value as well.
For [0,3] it should return 3-5 for the range of x values and 0-2 for the range of y values.

this is the function I have wrote:

```
std::pair<int, int> getBlock(const double val) const {
        double ourBlock = ceil(val / sqrt(size));
        int blockSize = sqrt(size);
        int currBlock = 1;
        int ourBlkStrt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (currBlock == ourBlock) {
                if (currBlock > 1) {
                    ourBlkStrt = i + blockSize;
                } else {
                    ourBlkStrt = i;
                }
                break;
            } else {
                if (i % blockSize == 0) {
                    currBlock++;
                }
            }
        }
        int ourBlkEnd = 0;
        if (ourBlkStrt != 1) {
        ourBlkEnd = ourBlkStrt + (blockSize);
    } else {
        ourBlkEnd = ourBlkStrt + (blockSize -1);
    }

        return std::pair<int, int>(ourBlkStrt, ourBlkEnd);

    }
```

My code isn't exactly the best way of doing it. It works in most cases, but sometimes it gives me a value outside of the required range.

Is there a better way of doing it? If so, could someone recommend/show me a method?

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let us define `f`:

```
std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> f(unsigned cell_index)
{
    const unsigned block_index = cell_index / 3;
    const unsigned lowest_block_index = block_index * 3;
    const unsigned highest_block_index = (block_index+1) * 3 - 1;
    return { lowest_block_index, highest_block_index };
}
```

or

```
std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> f(unsigned cell_index)
{
    switch (cell_index)
    {
       case 0: return { 0, 2 };
       case 1: return { 3, 5 };
       case 2: return { 6, 8 };
     }
     return { -1, -1 };
}
```

You could check that:

```
f(0) == { 0, 2 };
f(1) == { 3, 5 };
f(2) == { 6, 8 };
```

Then, the cell designed as `[y, x]` has range `[f(y).first, f(x).first]--[f(y).second, f(x).second]`.

Comment: Or even a `constexpr std::map<unsigned, std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>> f = { { 0, {0, 2} }, { 1, {3, 5} }, { 2, {6, 8} } };`.